Not possible to provide a lifetime when using Iterator
I'm trying to create a archive file reader (like ZIP or TAR). It should be possible to get the file entries of the archive using archive.records(). And the Records struct returned by this implements an Iterator to get each file of the archive.
But I have a problem with lifetime when implementing next() of the iterator as the trait doesn't know about the lifetime. How to get the lifetime working here?
(I assume the reader: &mut self.reader will cause problems too, because it can be borrowed only once)
// minimal example

use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, Read, Take},
    path::{Path, PathBuf},
};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut archive = Archive {
        reader: File::open("testfile")?,
    };
    let mut records = archive.records();
    for mut record in records {
        record.extract("outfile")?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

struct Archive<R: ?Sized> {
    reader: R,
}

struct Records<'a> {
    reader: &'a mut dyn Read,
}

struct Record<'a> {
    filename: PathBuf,
    reader: Take<&'a mut dyn Read>,
}

impl<R: Read> Archive<R> {
    pub fn records(&mut self) -> Records {
        Records {
            reader: &mut self.reader,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Records<'a> {
    type Item = Record<'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(Record {
            filename: PathBuf::new(),
            reader: (self.reader as &'a mut dyn Read).take(123),
        })
    }
}

impl<'a> Record<'a> {
    pub fn extract<P: AsRef<Path>>(&mut self, dest: P) -> io::Result<()> {
        let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
        self.reader.read(&mut buf)?;
        // TODO: Extract to file
        Ok(())
    }
}


REPL: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e854c87fbedf6e5369c97ab24691192

std::iter::Iterator does not allow items borrowing from self, you'll have to use a lending_iterator::LendingIterator or something similar instead.

I had a look into tar-rs source code and they are using a wrapper struct Entries->EntriesFields. I assume this makes it possible. But I'm not sure which is the crucial part: https://github.com/alexcrichton/tar-rs/blob/main/src/archive.rs#L265

The key difference is that EntriesFields only holds a reference to Archive, it doesn't give out refernces to itself but to the external Archive instead.
